# How can I define this function before I call it?

Tags: c++, function, user-defined-functions

I am a student working on a small homework project that I need help with. I am making a small turn-based game in which I have 2 problems.

The game's code:

```
#include<iostream.h>

class player
{
public:
    int health;
    char name[15];
    int atk;
    int mgatk;
    int agi;
    int def;
    int mgdef;
    int turnvalid;
    int type;
    int ctr;

    void turnend(player, player);
    void attack(player, player);
    void block(player, player);
    void menu(player, player);
};

void turnend(player p1, player p2)
{
    if(p1.turnvalid == 1)
    {
        menu(p1, p2);
    }
    else
    {
        menu(p2, p1);
    }
}

void attack(player p1, player p2)
{
    if(p1.turnvalid == 1)
        if(p1.type == 1)
        {
            p2.health = p2.health - (p1.atk/p2.def)*100;
        }
        else if(p1.type == 2)
        {
            p2.health = p2.health - (p1.mgatk/p2.mgdef)*100;
        }
    p1.turnvalid = 0;
    turnend(p1, p2);
}

void block(player p1, player p2)
{
    if(p1.type == 1)
    {
        p2.health = p2.health - (p1.atk/p2.def)*50;
    }
    else if(p1.type == 2)
    {
        p2.health = p2.health - (p1.mgatk/p2.mgdef)*50;
    }
    p1.turnvalid = 0;
    turnend(p1, p2);
}

void menu(player p1, player p2)
{
    int ch;
    cout<< "What will you do? \n1.Attack\n2.Block\n3.Counter";
    cin >> ch;
    switch(ch)
    {
    case '1':
        attack(p1, p2);
        break;  
    case '2':
        block(p1, p2);
        break;
    case '3':
    default:
        {
            cout<< "\nWrong choice! Enter again...\n";
            menu(p1, p2);
        }
    }
}

// this is not a part I am currently using because I can't
// figure out how to make it work
void counter(player p1, player p2)
{
    cout<< "Player " << p1.name << "countered!";
}

void main()
{
    cout<<"Beginning the game! Know your options!\nAttack to deal damage.\n"
          "Block to reduce damage taken.\nCounter to take damage, then deal "
          "twice the damage you took on the same turn.";
}
```

In this turn-based game, players have 2 choices right now: attack or block. They run fine, but the problem comes up when I redirect them to the turn menu again. Whenever I call that function, it says:
*[Error] c:\users\vive\desktop\not games\utilities\c++     programs\game2.cpp:27: E2268 Call to undefined function 'menu' in function     turnend(player,player)*

this probably happens because I defined turnend before I defined menu. But if I define menu before turnend, this happens:

*[Error] c:\users\madhav\desktop\not games\utilities\c++ programs\game2.cpp:30: E2268 Call to undefined function 'attack' in function menu(player,player)*

*[Error] c:\users\madhav\desktop\not games\utilities\c++ programs\game2.cpp:34: E2268 Call to undefined function 'block' in function menu(player,player)*

I'm essentially trapped, and I don't know what to do. No matter which one I define first, I get an error. I've declared them all in the class player itself, so why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Also, if someone can tell me how I can make the counter work I would really appreciate it. What I want is to deal double the damage taken, and make the counter go last. This would allow the player doing to counter to take the damage first, then return double the damage. And as for the stats like atk, mgatk, etc., I will affix them to two different 'classes' of characters, which will be determined by the int variable 'type'.

Any kind of help, criticism, advice etc. on the program is really appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: You declared a class containing several methods. Then you proceeded to define several global functions that happen to have the same names as the class methods. However they are not class methods. That's your problem. Go back and review your C++ book in order to learn how to properly define class methods.

Comment: `<iostream.h>` and `void main` never were legal in standard C++. You should get some more up to date learning material, the one you are using now appears to be from the 90s.

Comment: @Baum _"appears to be from the 90s"_ of the last milleniums last century to emphasize that.

Comment: Use the class scope operator `player::`, even that old compiler got to do that correctly: `void player::turnend(player p1, player p2)`.

Comment: For even a substantial chunk of the 90s that was not correct code. Standardisation occurred in 1998 but a process led up to it. I'd call it 1980s learning material. /cc @Baum

Comment: @plasmacel Sorry! I'm not very good at C++ :I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You error is caused by missing `player::` in front of function's name in definitions. 
Simply replace

```
void attack(player p1, player p2){
(...)
```

with

```
void player::attack(player p1, player p2){
(...)
```

and so on.

When you don't mark defined function as member of class by putting class name before function's name (or define it inside class) compiler will recognize it as completely different function.

But probably better for you will be learn about dividing code into header- and source- files for avoiding more complicated mistakes in future.